# Facebook Graph API: get sum of likes made to friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get a list of the sums of likes/shares the calling user has made on his/her friends' objects over a specified time frame broken out by friend, without having to iterate over all objects that a user's friends have posted, tallying their likes from that user, and then re-doing that for all of the user's friends?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible with the current Graph API.